# IIS Express will not start

Tags: iis-express

I'm just putting this one out there since its a Google Zero-resulter which means I win a prize?

Cannot start IIS Express 7.5 after reinstall from one account, but I can when logged-in under my other domain account.

What's odd is that the account it fails under is my 'super' account with local admin rights, and is also the account I installed it under.

The error stems from diprestr.dll not loading...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe /trace:error
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 2068729
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 2068744
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 2068744
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 2068744
Failed to load global module C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\diprestr.dll
Failed processing with hr = 8007007e
Error loading global modules.  hr = 8007007e
Terminating W3_SERVER object
Start listenerChannel http:0
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 2069774
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 2069774
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 2069774
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 2069774
Failed to load global module C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\diprestr.dll
Failed processing with hr = 8007007e
Error loading global modules.  hr = 8007007e
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Report ListenerChannel stopped due to failure; ProtocolId:http, ListenerChannelId:0
Process Model Shutdown called
Failed to start 'HostedWASStart'.  Error = 38246848
HostableWebCore activation failed.
Unable to start iisexpress.

The specified module could not be found.
For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error).
```

Any got any ideas? I'll try Process Monitor and see.

So far, IIS Express is proving to be just another thing to learn and go wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check that the user its failing has a `IISExpress\config` folder in their home folder. If not then copy it over from the user where IISExpress is working. This is a common fault when the config files/folders are missing.

Comment: Cheers John, the folder was there so I cleared out any existing files and its solved it! I owe you a pint.

Comment: This answer helps the specific user but not me.. Where can I get this folder?

Comment: It would depend on your OS and specific settings but generally :- C:\users\<USERNAME>\My Documents\IISExpress\config

Comment: Like @Luke - cleared everything in the config folder and iisexpress magically found its missing module :) Note that your config folder may not be on disk C if you have your 'My Documents' folder on other drive.

Comment: Still now working. I'm getting this error ``` 
The specified module could not be found.
For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error). ```

Comment: In my case, this folder was moved to OneDrive and few files where not downloaded locally (they were only on OneDrive). Marking this folder as "always keep local copy" helped.

Answer (score 31):

To clarify John's comment - the directory will be something like `C:\users\jmitchell\My Documents\IISExpress\config`.  I assume John is correct in that if it doesn't exist you would need to create the directory.

Alternatively the directory could already exist and just be corrupted.  This is what I believe happened in my case.  I had previously installed WebMatrix but ran into all sorts of issues today.  After uninstalling IIS Express, Web Platform Installer, WebMatrix, and some SQL Server Management Objects, and then reinstalling WPI & WebMatrix, I came across this post.

I actually got IIS Express to run successfully after deleting the config directory mentioned above, and then re-running `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe /trace:error`

And I **ONLY** wasted two hours of my day on this!  Thanks Microsoft!

Answer (score 22):

using `jetbrains rider` I had to remove this config file found here and that worked
`\.idea\config\applicationhost.config`

think this was caused when I removed VS

---

On another occasion I did get this issue due to custom HOST name and that along with some other PORT binding issues was resolved by running `rider` as admin.

Comment: absolute life saver

Answer (score 7):

I has 2 things to do to make it work

1. try as everybody do

   1.1. Delete all files in  C:\{users}\My Documents\IIS Express\config
   (Note: Don't worry it will re-create it automatically, if you afraid you can copy to some other place first)

---

2. If it still not work, try this below

   2.1. Delete all files in {your project}\.vs\{your project}\config
   (Note: .vs\ folder is hidden make sure you show hidden folder first)

   2.2. in Visual Studio > Right click on your Project > select Properties

   2.3. Select "Web" Tab > in Project URL > change your port
   (Example: change from http://localhost:1096/ to http://localhost:1097/)

   2.4. Save and run your Project again.

Comment: Thanks a million, changing the port did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Only Deleting config folder did not work for me. Also i did this

"Delete the following file <>.vs\config\applicationhost.config, the .vs folder may be hidden"

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a25b14d-02e5-4adc-bd79-4d215893fed2/vs-2013-unable-to-start-program-cprogram-files-x86iis-expressiisexpressexe?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might need to change the line

```
applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
```

to

```
applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool"
```

in the file...

```
C:\users\jmitchell\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

if you continue to get the same error (as I did) after following the instructions on the post above. The issue being solved here is that you don't have .NET4 installed, and so are reverting to using .NET2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after upgrading to Web Platform Installer 5.

The quick fix for me was to also upgrade to Webmatrix 3 (http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

Answer (score 0):

After deleting config folder it was still not working then i followed 
[this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a25b14d-02e5-4adc-bd79-4d215893fed2/vs-2013-unable-to-start-program-cprogram-files-x86iis-expressiisexpressexe?forum=visualstudiogeneral) article and hit ctrl + F5..so it did run

Answer (score 0):

download and install the IIS Express server and try to run again the project.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/

Answer (score 0):

Posting a linkback here + some more detail on Rider since this answer is the first that comes up in Google

This happened for me when launching a project in Rider which was working in VS 2019

This can happen if the bitness of IISExpress is incorrectly set -> your x86 `program files` folder instead of the 64bit `program files` folder

[image]

[IIS Express 800700c1 error with Visual Studio 2015 ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965524/iis-express-800700c1-error-with-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I had installed the Asp.Net Core Module / AspNetCoreModuleV2, which got added to my `applicationhost.config` like this:

```xml
<add name="AspNetCoreModuleV2" image="C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll" />
```

This caused the following startup trace:

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 105458609
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 105458625
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 105458625
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 105458625
Failed processing with hr = 800700c1
Error loading global modules.  hr = 800700c1
Terminating W3_SERVER object
Start listenerChannel http:0
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 105459796
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 105459796
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 105459796
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 105459796
Failed processing with hr = 800700c1
Error loading global modules.  hr = 800700c1
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable to start iisexpress.
```

After removing the line above, this issue went away.