# My IIS Express do not work, and give me this ERRORS

Tags: .net, iis, iis-express

this is the error i get in the cmd when i tried to run iisexpress.exe/trace:error

```
C:\Users\Hatem>"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"/trace:error
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 70060343
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 70060359
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 70060359
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 70060359
Failed processing with hr = 8007007e
Error loading global modules.  hr = 8007007e
Terminating W3_SERVER object
Start listenerChannel http:0
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 70061375
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 70061375
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 70061375
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 70061375
Failed processing with hr = 8007007e
Error loading global modules.  hr = 8007007e
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable to start iisexpress.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the iisexpress\config file for the failing user is present. If absent, copy it over from a working user's config.

the per user config should be in the c:\users\\iisexpress folder or so.

Comment: the file exists !!
did not help !!
i am using VS 2013 and win8
earlier in my win7 i had no problems

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I looked at this tread [IIS Express will not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687267/iis-express-will-not-start)

Just delete C:\users\\My Documents\IISExpress\config and run iisexpress again

Comment: Why is this the case? A lot of answers say to do that and it WORKS? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue and I have resolved the issue by removing the below line from the applicationhost.config file.

```
<add name="iisnode" image="C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode-express\iisnode.dll" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This article solved my question

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a25b14d-02e5-4adc-bd79-4d215893fed2/vs-2013-unable-to-start-program-cprogram-files-x86iis-expressiisexpressexe?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Refer to your description, please have a try with the following to troubleshot this issue:

Ctrl+F5 (Start without debugging) to test
Close VS 2013 and run it as administrator, then debug this web application
Close all VS instances and try to delete the automatically-created IISExpress folder, which is usually located at %userprofile%/Documents, start VS will auto create it again.
Delete the following file <>.vs\config\applicationhost.config, the .vs folder may be hidden
Right click the project name and choose Properties>Web>Servers and modify the portal number
Meanwhile, you can have a look at the similar issues as below:

Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server

Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio Development Web server.Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe