# Local Azure Cloud Service (Emulator) will not run

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-sdk-.net, azure-compute-emulator

I have got a new computer, and while the cloud project runs on my old computer (Azure SDK 2.4, VS 2013) it refused to do so on the new computer.

I have installed the following:

1. 2015 Ultimate CTP installed & Azure 2.5 sdk (didn't work)
2. 2013 Premium & Azure 2.5 sdk (so tried using this instead - no dice)
3. In addition I have created a new cloud project and added the site to it.
4. The MVC site will run if it was the startup project.
5. Documents is synched to OneDrive, however I have made all files available offline.
6. Tried to install regular IIS, including the Development Features. Switched the Cloud Project to use IIS instead, and it still bombs.

When using IISExpress this was the error I got.

C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /trace:error /config:"C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\<>\temp\temp\RoleTemp\applicationHost.config <-- This file is missing.

Attempt to re-add the applicationHost.config to the above folder manually, results in the file being removed immediately.

I have spent far too much time on this, and am at the end of my wit. Any thought what else I might be missing?

=============================================================

Created VM, installed VS2013 and and 2.5 sdk, still will not deploy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11687328/43846 ?

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by:

1. Uninstalling all .NET framework SDKs, and their related language packs. (Especially the 4.5.3)
2. Install .NET framework 4.5.1 for visual studio 2013
3. Change all project types to 4.5.1

Hit F5.

Took a long time but there, may be this will help somebody else out there.