# IIS Express 800700c1 error with Visual Studio 2015 ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

This is what happens when I run IIS Express with the config visual studio made for my ASP.Net MVC project. If I run iisexpress.exe with no parameters, that server starts up fine. I don't know how I should hunt this problem down. I think the error code means something is corrupted, but I don't see how that is likely.

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 64585693
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 64585693
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 64585693
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 64585693
Failed processing with hr = 800700c1
Error loading global modules.  hr = 800700c1
Terminating W3_SERVER object
Start listenerChannel http:0
Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 64586816
W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 64586816
W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 64586816
W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 64586816
Failed processing with hr = 800700c1
Error loading global modules.  hr = 800700c1
Terminating W3_SERVER object
InitComplete event signalled
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable TO start iisexpress.
```

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you use the wrong bitness of IISExpress for the website. If it is a 32 bit site, use `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`; if it is a 64 bit site, use `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`.